How to Implement 'game rules' when training a Deep Q Network
I am trying to make a Deep-Q-network that teaches itself to play modified versions of tictactoe (a m,n,k-game)
I want to make sure the network does not place a mark where there already is a mark
I currently have two ideas for it:

The agent can select the next action only from empty grids
Let the agent choose any grid and give a penalty if it chooses a already-occupied grid(and end the episode)

I'm pretty sure both would work, but which one will be more efficient while training?
Trying option 1, but i'm not sure the Q-values for 'ilegal grids' are getting smaller, and each episode seems to take too long

Well, usually either you choose an environment (such as OpenAI/DeepMind's environments for various games like Atari Breakout etc.), there the rules are already implemented in a way, or you program your own environment. Probably you choose the second case. I would recommend programming the environment in which your RL model runs to include a Markov decision process which describes the set of states and actions you can take in a state. This would include your rule (1). I'm a bit puzzled now how that'd go effectively in an infinite grid game but there must be ways to represent this well as a MDP

I would go for the second option. However, another option that came to mind is to make it such that the policy network can only choose actions from the legal set of actions. Suppose a policy network that outputs action probabilities, and suppose some action picking method (i.e. sampling from a categorical distribution), you can exclude the actions that are illegal in the current state and adapt the categorical distribution accordingly, such that you only pick legal actions. This will ultimately result in an policy that will avoid illegal actions in the long term.
